# Get file from MSI in wix Custom Action (Before="InstallFinalize")

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

Need to CustomAction during installation to get the file nlbdb.bak from MSI. How to get his path?

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
  <Directory Id="BACKUP" Name="BACKUP"/>
<Directory/>
<DirectoryRef Id="BACKUP">
  <Component Id="VMBackup">
    <File Id="Backup" Name="nlbdb.bak" Source="BACKUP\nlbdb.bak" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

CA

```
[CustomAction]
public static  ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
{
  string Directory = "";//get file path nlbdb.bak
  bool test = File.Exists(Directory);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Is this an upgrade and you are trying to copy files before they are replaced? Or is this at the end of your install and you want to copy a just-installed file somewhere? If it's this, then your CA needs to be deferred so it runs after files have been installed.

Comment: I create new installer. Before completing the installation (the files are not copied to the selected folder) need to get in CA nlvdb.bak file for certain operations. So here's how to get this file? In the folder BACKUP it yet. It will be shown after the successful completion CA.

Comment: The issue is that the file you want to copy is in a CAB inside the MSI file, which is where Windows will install it from. You could copy it after it's been installed though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a wix property inside your custom action using

```
var propertyValue = session["MY_PROPERTY"];
```

In your case you'd use that to get the value of `BACKUP` which will be where the file was installed. Obviously you would also concatenate the file name as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the session.Format Method like this:

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CustomAction1(Session session)
    {
        string path = session.Format("[#Backup]");
        bool test = File.Exists(path);

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }

    <CustomAction Id="CustomAction1" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="yes"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="CustomAction1" Before="InstallFinalize">Not Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```